# Service layer ModelState not updating in .net Web API

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api, service-layer, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm implementing an MVC solution that has some Web API endpoints for various data queries.  I'm using [the techniques described in this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs) to separate my validation concerns to a Services layer.

This post has a **TL;DR** at the end if you want to skip to the specific question.

Here is my `ApiController` code:

```
[Authorize]
public class FriendsController : ApiController
{
    private IItemService _service;

    public FriendsController()
    {
        _service = new ItemService(new HttpModelStateWrapper(ModelState), new ViewModelRepository());
    }

    public FriendsController(IItemService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // GET api/friends
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return _service.GetFriends(User.Identity.Name);
    }


 .
 .
 .

    // POST api/friends
    public void Post(Guid id)
    {
        var user = _service.AddFriend(User.Identity.Name, id);  // Handles error and should update ViewModel
        NotificationAsyncController.AddNotification(user);
    }
}
```

and the code for `_service.AddFriend(User.Identity.Name, id);` looks like this:

```
    public User AddFriend(string userName, Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            return _repository.AddFriend(userName, id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _validationDictionary.AddError("AddFriend", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And `_validationDictionary` looks like this:

```
public class HttpModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{
    private ModelStateDictionary ModelState;

    public HttpModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
    {
        this.ModelState = ModelState;
    }

    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        if (ModelState != null)
            ModelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return ModelState == null ? false : ModelState.IsValid; }
    }
}
```

Well, I found out that if `_repository.AddFriend(userName, id);` throws an error and `_validationDictionary.AddError("AddFriend", e.Message);` is called, the ModelState object that is in `_validationDictionary` does not update the ModelState object that resides in the `FriendsController`.

In other words, after `AddError` is called, the ModelState in the `HttpModelStateWrapper` is not valid, but once that method returns and scope is returned to the `FriendsController`, its ModelState has not updated and is still valid!

### TL;DR

How do I get the ModelState object that I've passed into the `HttpModelStateWrapper` in the ctor of the `FriendsController` have its changes reflected in the ModelState object of the `FriendsController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just passing the whole controller and that gave me access to the ModelState object